# Using toString() to print out the date with a 'this' passed in

Tags: java, constructor, tostring

So I just learned about toString and i made a program to display the date with a string that says the date but for some reason it repeats the date separately underneath after I run it I get:

The date for today is 6/5/15

6/5/15

```
public class Main{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date= new Date(6,5,15);
    System.out.println(date);

  }
}
```

...

```
public class Date{

  private int month;
  private int day;
  private int year;

  public Date(int m, int d, int y){
    month = m;
    day = d;
    year = y;

    System.out.printf("The date for today is %s\n", this);
  }

  public String toString(){
    return String.format("%d/%d/%d", month, day, year);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `System.out.printf(...)` in your constructor does?

Comment: What do you think `System.out.println(tntobject);` does?

Comment: You have a `printf` call in your constructor and a `println` call in your main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `System.out.printf("The date for today is %s\n", this);` from your constructor, and modify the print statement in `main( )` as `System.out.printf("The date for today is ", tntobject);`

Comment: When you are already printing the date in the constructor `public TnT( )`, there is no need to print it again in the `main( )`. Personally, I would suggest you to print the date from `main( )`, as we generally use a constructor only for initialising values.

Answer (score 1):

By creating an Object of a certain Class you are calling the constructor.

In this case the constuctor has already got the line System.out.print( //code );

So in order to print it out you just write:

TnT tnt = new TnT(5,6,7);

Answer (score 1):

Do not print inside the `constructor`. It isn't a good practice !
Problem here is that you are printing the date inside the constructor once, and you are again printing it inside the `main`. Remove the

`System.out.printf("The date for today is %s\n", this);`

from the constructor. Then inside the main method, 
add

`System.out.printf("The date for today is" + tntobject);`